# Loading JavaScript on a website in KaiOS browser

Tags: javascript, html, kaios

I'm making a tiny website to open it in KaiOS browser (firmware version 2.5.1). No matter how I do it, the script part does not work at all, although on my PC browser the code runs just fine.

My HTML and JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Radio relay for KaiOS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Radio relay for KaiOS browser</h1>
    <a href="https://www.silver.ru/">Серебряный дождь</a>
    <audio class="audio-station" controls src="http://silverrain.hostingradio.ru/silver128.mp3"></audio>
    <p>Now playing: TBD</p>
    <a href="https://asebeia.su/radio">Асебия</a>
    <audio class="audio-station" id="asebeia-station" controls src="https://azura.asebeia.su/listen/music/radio.mp3"></audio>
    <p id="now-playing-asebeia">Now playing: </p>
    <p>for personal use by A.N., last update 4 Sep 2023</p>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
// to test on the actual device if .js file loads up correctly
// it does not :(
let a = document.createElement("h1");
a.innerHTML = "Hello";
document.querySelector("body").prepend(a);

function stopOtherStations(currentAudioElement) {
    let audioElements = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
    Array.from(audioElements).forEach(element => {
        if (element !== currentAudioElement) element.pause();
    });
};

async function getAsebeiaNowPlaying() {
    let response = await fetch("https://azura.asebeia.su/api/nowplaying/1");
    let nowPlaying = await response.json();
    return nowPlaying.now_playing.song.text;
};

window.onload = function (event) {
    let audioElements = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
    Array.from(audioElements).forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("play", (event) => {
            stopOtherStations(element);
        });
    });

    // asebeia-specific code
    let audioAsebeia = document.getElementById("asebeia-station");
    let intervalId;

    audioAsebeia.addEventListener("playing", async (event) => {
        let nowPlayingAsebeia = document.getElementById("now-playing-asebeia");
        nowPlayingAsebeia.innerHTML = `Now playing: ${await getAsebeiaNowPlaying()}`;
        intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
            console.log(await getAsebeiaNowPlaying());
            nowPlayingAsebeia.innerHTML = `Now playing: ${await getAsebeiaNowPlaying()}`;
        }, 10000);
    });

    audioAsebeia.addEventListener("pause", (event) => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });

};
```

I've tried various ways to load the script, including writing it inline. Does not work. I see no compatibility issues - the KaiOS browser should support ES6. The web app is actually deployed here: [monkfish-app-4larl.ondigitalocean.app](https://monkfish-app-4larl.ondigitalocean.app)

Comment: Do you get any errors on the browser console?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: No, on my PC I get no errors at all. Only a warning about mixed content (code gets data from an unsecured resource via HTTP) and that's it. I have no means to access the device console, however.

Comment: I've tried different ways to load up the script. All of them work on PC browsers, none on KaiOS. I've tried to load my code into Babel transpiler to see if there's some modern stuff to polyfill, but it seems that I did not use any cutting-edge JS.

Comment: Why not try to run more simplified code first to see how far you can get?

Comment: I've reduced the JS to simply adding an h1 programmatically, the script still does not execute.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KaiOS 2.5.x based on Gecko 48
You cannot use such function like await, async, etc

Before use some functions on KaiOS, check do it supported on Gecko 48

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The script still does not load, even if I strip it down to just adding an h1 and prepending it to the body of HTML. Maybe there is something else? Does KaiOS browser in general support JS? Maybe Gecko 48 is just for the applications, but not the browsing?

Comment: I've discovered that prepend method is not supported by this engine. I've changed it and got my "Hello" on the page via JS. I'll try and refactor the whole thing to promises and/or some really old JS to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! As pointed out by [Tatyana Korshakova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9972399/tatyana-korshakova), the problem was KaiOS 2.5.1 browser using Gecko 48 browser engine. It is more outdated than I assumed. I learned that at some point Firefox and Gecko versions were synced, so to determine incompatible code I was able to refer to Firefox 48 on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/). Indeed, it does not support async/await, fetch API and many other things.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).